# pandas read_json gives multiple columns instead of rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to convert json to pandas dataframe using read_json,
but it is always creating extra columns instead of rows

json:

```
'[{"1981121": {"Summary": "Tasa"}}, {"1981123": {"Summary": "This fox only jumps on the top"}}]'
```

code:

```
pd.read_json(json,orient='index')
```

result:

```
                 0                                              1
1981121  {'Summary': 'Tasa'}                                   NaN
1981123         NaN                {'Summary': 'This fox only jumps on the top'}
```

i have tried different values for 'orient' arg yet it is the same

how can i get dataframe in this manner

```
               0         
1981121  {'Summary': 'Tasa'}                                           
1981123  {'Summary': 'This fox only jumps on the top'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas expects each record to be a tuple, not a dict.  Here's one way to make it work:

```
items = [next(iter(d.items())) for d in json]
pd.DataFrame.from_items(items, orient='index', columns=['Summary'])
```

Then you get:

```
                                Summary
1981121                            Tasa
1981123  This fox only jumps on the top
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed! Any advice on how can i improve to gain knowledge,
like knowing pandas expects to be tuple?